# How to print this using loops only

Tags: java, loops

I just want to print this in simple java program using loops only.

> `----*----`
>   `---*-*---`
>   `--*-*-*--`
>   `-*-*-*-*-`
>   `*-*-*-*-*`

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @tanmay [tag:java] is already added, in title "Java" is not required !!!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for people to recognize? Moreover, it was there even in the original title.

Comment: @TanmayPatil [It is not necessary to use tags in title,](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208) community has a tag system with the soul purpose to recognize technology/language of question.

Comment: Please at least show an attempt. This way, someome can guide you to the right path

Answer (score 4):

### Break the problem in small steps.

1. **Loops for printing correct rectangle without patterns**

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
           System.out.print("-");
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
   ```

   This would give following output.

   > `---------`
   >   `---------`
   >   `---------`
   >   `---------`
   >   `---------`
2. **Create pattern using if condition.**

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
           if ((j - i) % 2 == 0) { // Condition for alternate stars
               System.out.print("*");
           } else {
               System.out.print("-");
           }
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
   ```

   This would give following output.

   > `*-*-*-*-*`
   >   `-*-*-*-*-`
   >   `*-*-*-*-*`
   >   `-*-*-*-*-`
   >   `*-*-*-*-*`
3. **Restrict pattern inside the triangular shape.**

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
           if (i + j > 3 && j - i < 5) { // Equations of straight lines in triangle
               if ((j - i) % 2 == 0) {   // Condition for alternate stars
                   System.out.print("*");
               } else {
                   System.out.print("-");
               }
           } else {
               System.out.print("-");
           }
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
   ```

   This would give following output.

   > `----*----`
   >   `---*-*---`
   >   `--*-*-*--`
   >   `-*-*-*-*-`
   >   `*-*-*-*-*`
4. **Refactor for condensed conditions**

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
           if (i + j > 3 && j - i < 5 && (j - i) % 2 == 0) {
               System.out.print("*");
           } else {
               System.out.print("-");
           }
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
   ```

   This would give following output.

   > `----*----`
   >   `---*-*---`
   >   `--*-*-*--`
   >   `-*-*-*-*-`
   >   `*-*-*-*-*`

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: the comment `Equations of straight lines in triangle` was most helpful.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 1):

try this :D

```
public static void main(String[] argu) {

    int index=8;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

        for(int j=index;j>0;j--) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        index--;
        if(i==4) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps give an explanation of your code is doing, and why it answers the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    for(int i=5;i>=1;i--){
            int otherSide = 10-i;
            int printStar = -1;     
        for(int j=1;j<=9;j++){

            if(j>=i && j<=otherSide){
                printStar*=-1;
                if(printStar==1) System.out.print("*");
                else System.out.print("-");
            }
            else
                System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Just find the start index of the * and the part where it is last printed. Print stars alternatingly inside the range.

Comment: You should explain how this works, rather than just handing it to him to copy & paste

Comment: Lol he changed the question. I should now change the answer.